# Can an Excel Document be Loaded into Memory, Populated, and Returned as Bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, export-to-excel

I've worked with Excel Interop before for the purposes of opening an Excel file, writing some data to it, and saving it.  Something like this:

```
public void WriteAFile()
{
    var xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
    var xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
    var xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    xlWorksheet.Name = "Some Name";

    // Write some contrived data
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        xlWorksheet.Cells[i + 1, 1] = i;
        xlWorksheet.Cells[i + 1, 2] = i + 1;
        //... and so on...
    }
    //... and so on...

    // Save the file
    xlWorkbook.SaveAs(
      @"",
      Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
      Missing.Value,
      Missing.Value,
      false,
      false,
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
      Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges,
      false,
      Missing.Value,
      Missing.Value,
      Missing.Value
    );

    xlWorkbook.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    xlApp.Quit();

    // release other resources, etc.
}
```

This works reasonably well for an application writing to a file on a local workstation.  However, now I'm working on a web application which needs to return a file to the user.  The catch is that the file on the file system can't be modified.  So what I need to do is:

1. Load a known Excel file into memory (note that the file is `.xlsm` and contains macro code, which will be run on the user's workstation when they download it).
2. Write known data to a known location in the file (for the sake of argument, some numeric values to the first few cells on sheet 99).
3. Stream that file from memory via the web application (the streaming part is trivial, it's getting the byte array in the first place that seems trickier to me).

I've Googled around, but haven't found much of anything.  Basically just instructions and examples which do what I'm already doing in my code above.  It also comes as no surprise when working with COM interop that my code above (which is pretty old) and other code I find online is all a bit dated.  We're using .NET 4.0, so anything that's available there is appropriate for us.

The extent of my experience with COM is pretty much fully displayed in the code above.  I'd prefer not to use COM at all for this, if that's at all possible.  But right now I'm just having trouble getting off the ground.  Can anybody point me in the right direction?  Maybe reference some classes or methods that would be of particular use here?  Thanks.

*P.S.* Another thing that kind of frightens me is the need for Excel on the web server, as well as the possibility of the Excel application opening on the console of the web server and hanging on a user-unseen error of some kind.  So any advice there is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) library.  (OpenXML by itself was... unwieldy.)  As a simple proof of concept for opening the file, writing a piece of data, and returning a byte array:

```
public byte[] GetExcelApplication(Guid sessionKey)
{
    // Input checking

    using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook(_excelFile))
    {
        var worksheets = workbook.Worksheets.Where(w => w.Name == "Session Key");
        if (worksheets.Count() < 1)
            throw new Exception("Excel file does not contain a worksheet called: Session Key");
        if (worksheets.Count() > 1)
            throw new Exception("Excel file contains multiple worksheets called: Session Key");

        var worksheet = worksheets.Single();
        var cell = worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = sessionKey.ToString();

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.SaveAs(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With c# 4.0 COM should be a bit easier since you can use dynamic. But it's then still COM. 
I use a thirt party product for this called [aspose cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx). I'm not working for them, but i realy like this product(even if it's not free). This save me a lot of trouble when dealing with excel.

Answer (score 0):

Doing something similar with COM I resorted to saving the generated Excel workbook to a temporary folder, sending it off and then deleting it. Not using COM wasn't really an option for me as the workbook also needed pivot tables and graphs generated.

Comment: This temporary file thing may end up being the route I take, given my research so far.  For now I'm using `Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xls"` as the file name.  It definitely feels hack-ish, but this is COM we're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Old-school, but [I wrote this a long time ago](http://naspinski.net/post/Complete-Web-Based-Excel-Spreadsheet-Builder.aspx) that constructs a workbook on the fly and exports it.  Maybe it can get you on the right track?

Comment: Hmm... This export utility looks a bit too simplified.  It's just writing an HTML table as Excel data, which I don't think the macro code within the template Excel file will be able to use.

Comment: Excel data is not complicated - you could even output the data as a csv and excel will recognize it.

Comment: A CSV definitely won't work, since it won't contain the macro code.  It's a fairly complex Excel-based "application" and I'm just populating some hidden sheets with data.